# Printing a list from a class in Python

Tags: python, class

My simplified code is below: it creates an animal, and places it inside a zoo. I want to print the list of animals within the zoo. Going round in circles with this!

```
class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Zoo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.animals = []

    def __str__(self):
        rep = ", ".join(self.animals)
        return rep

    def add(self, name):
        self.animals.append(Animal(name))

def main():

    while True:
        zoo = Zoo()
        animal = input("add an animal: ")
        zoo.add(animal)
        print(zoo)

main()
```

Comment: `', '.join(animal.name for animal in self.animals)`

Comment: @AlG `Animal(name)` in `Zoo.add()` creates the animal - not particularly clean.

Comment: Probably not the cleanest but I am new to Python.  Can you suggest a cleaner way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply refer to the `name` property of `Animal` in your `Zoo.__str__()`, e.g.:

```
def __str__(self):
    return ', '.join(animal.name for animal in self.animals)
```

Now `print(zoo)` should work correctly.

However this doesn't provide a lot of encapsulation if say you wanted to change what it means to print an animal, e.g. height, size, etc. So perhaps a more encapsulated form would be:

```
class Animal(object):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Zoo(object):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return ", ".join(str(animal) for animal in self.animals)
```

Now when you `print(zoo)` the `Animal` class is responsible for its own string presentation.
Just as a note: you probably should create the Animal instance outside of Zoo, what happens if you decide to create a class hierarchy of `Animal`s (e.g. `Mammal`) that has different behaviours, your `Zoo` class would only know about `Animal`s.

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Zoo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.animals = []
    def __str__(self):
        return ", ".join(str(animal) for animal in self.animals)
    def add(self, animal):
        self.animals.append(animal)

def main():
    zoo = Zoo()
    while True:
        animal = Animal(input("add an animal: "))
        zoo.add(animal)
        print(zoo)

main()
```

This would still behave properly if you create a `Mammal` class:

```
class Mammal(Animal):
    ...

zoo.add(Mammal(...))
print(zoo)
```

Answer (score 3):

The added `__repr__` Method to the Animal returns us the name.

The zoo = Zoo() has to be outside of the loop, this makes sure that we do not create a new zoo with every iteration.

Then we print the list (zoo.animals).

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name



class Zoo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.animals = []
    def __str__(self):
        rep = ", ".join(self.animals)
        return rep
    def add(self, name):
        self.animals.append(Animal(name))



def main():
    zoo = Zoo()
    while True:
        animal = input("add an animal: ")
        zoo.add(animal)
        print(zoo.animals)


main()
```

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful.

Comment: And this doesn't work to `print(zoo)`. `print()` looks for `__str__()` or `__repr__()` in the objects to `print`, so `print(zoo.animals)` will work but because `str.join()` doesn't, `print(zoo)` will raise `TypeError`. In addition, `__str__()` is probably the more correct method to implement, `__repr__()` is intended to be able to reconstruct the type so would normally print out the class name, e.g. `Animal.__repr__(self): return 'Animal('+self.name+')'`